# get record by date range in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, range

I want to search records between two dates in CodeIgniter  I have tried many methods but not getting required result.

**My Model**

```
function search($date1 , $date2 ){
    $this->db->where('date<',$date1);
    $this->db->where('date >',$date2);
    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result;
}
```

**My controller**

```
function getsearch(){
     $date1 = $this->input->post('txtdate1');   // 02-06-2015
     $date2 = $this->input->post('txtdate2');   // 19-06-2015
     $data['result']  = $this->result_model->search($date1,$date2);
     $this->load->view("search_view",$data);
}
```

Now I want all rows between 2 to 19 but I am getting nothing.
**Note:**  *date* type in mysql is *varchar*

Comment: in your table, how are the dates fielld types defined?

Comment: Well, type of `date` field may be an issue. Dates are compared in a different way than strings (varchars).

Comment: @CodeGodie he wrote it's varchar

Comment: change `'date<'` to `'date <'` . The space might be giving you issues

Comment: I see. But why `varchar`? is it possible to change it to `date` ?

Comment: well i think i need to change the type of date field ?

Comment: definitely. There are ways to compare a string, but why would you store dates as `varchar`? Change it to date. its more accurate

Comment: You are trying to find out the date that is less than 02-06-2015 and greater than 19-06-2015?

Answer (score 0):

`02-06-2015` is a really suboptimal way to store dates in SQL, because they don't collate sensibly.  If you can switch to a `DATE` or `DATETIME` data type, you'll be able to do cool stuff like indexing on the date column. But that's not what you asked.

Also, I wonder if you have your inequalities wrong? What's the start and end of the range of dates you want to search?

To answer your specific question:

The [`DATE_FORMAT()` MySQL function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) will convert your char dates to collatable dates. In particular,

```
  DATE_FORMAT('02-06-2015', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

gets you a `DATE` object from your dates.

So this sort of php code will work

```
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') < ","DATE_FORMAT('$date1', '%d-%m-%Y')");
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') > ","DATE_FORMAT('$date2', '%d-%m-%Y'):);
```

If `$date2` is '01-06-2015' and `$date1` is '04-06-2015' this will give back the records that fall on the second and third days of June.

You may want this instead for a [$date1,$date2] range.

```
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') >= ","DATE_FORMAT('$date1', '%d-%m-%Y')");
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') <  ","DATE_FORMAT('$date2', '%d-%m-%Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY");
```

Notice your `date` column is wrapped up in a function. That defeats the use of any index to do the table search on dates. If your `date` column had a `DATE` datatype, this would work. If you had an index on `date` MySQL would use a highly efficient range scan.

```
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') >= ","'$date1'");
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') <  ","'$date2' + INTERVAL 1 DAY");
```

In raw SQL this would come out to...

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') >= '$date1'
  AND DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') <  '$date2' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```